# Clean installed Surface Book can't find TPM module

Tags: windows-10, drivers, tpm

I've cleanly installed Windows 10 on the Surface Book and even installed the official [drivers package](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49497) for the Surface Book but when I go to enable Bitlocker, I receive this message: "'This device can’t use a Trusted Platform Module. Your administrator must select the 'Allow BitLocker without a compatible TPM' option in the 'Require additional authentication at startup' policy for OS volumes."

I've checked the Device Manager and can't find anything resembling a TPM module. I've activated the TPM module in the UEFI settings.

Browsing the official drivers, I can't find a driver with a name indicating it is a TPM module.

How do I get my Surface Book to recognize the TPM module which I know was enabled when I first purchased it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this in the UEFI by changing Secure Boot to allowing Microsoft and Certificates of Authority and by turning off the TPM module, booting, then rebooting into the UEFI once more and turning on the TPM followed be a second reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still having this issue after following the Tao's method above. Has anyone else found an alternative solution?

Just like Tao, TPM is enabled at BIOS but does NOT appear in device manager at all (even if you click show hidden devices).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1144573)